# Get execution time function in python

Tags: python, function, time, measure

I create this working function for getting time of another function:

```
def get_execution_time(function, args, numberOfExecTime=1):
    """Return the execution time of a function in seconds.

    """

    return round(Timer(partial(function, args)).timeit(numberOfExecTime), 5)
```

By the way I have a problem: I can't give multiple input (args) to the function to be timed.
How can I do that? Is partial the right tool?

I tried decorator but I can't store the time which is what I need for doing some statistics.

Answer (score 4):

If you can sacrifice ability to have default value for `numberOfExecTime` argument you can do it like that:

```
from timeit import Timer
from functools import partial

def get_execution_time(function, numberOfExecTime, *args, **kwargs):
    """Return the execution time of a function in seconds."""
    return round(Timer(partial(function, *args, **kwargs))
                 .timeit(numberOfExecTime), 5)

def foo(a, b, c = 12):
    print a, b, c

get_execution_time(foo, 1, 3, 4, c = 14)
```

Or you can do it like that and still have default value for `numberOfExecTime`:

```
from timeit import Timer
from functools import partial

def get_execution_time(function, *args, **kwargs):
    """Return the execution time of a function in seconds."""
    numberOfExecTime = kwargs.pop('numberOfExecTime', 1)
    return round(Timer(partial(function, *args, **kwargs))
                 .timeit(numberOfExecTime), 5)

def foo(a, b, c = 1):
    print a, b, c

get_execution_time(foo, 1, 2, c = 2)
# => 1 2 2

get_execution_time(foo, 4, 5, c = 3, numberOfExecTime = 2)
# => 4 5 3
# => 4 5 3
```

Comment: You don't even have to sacrifice the default. Just omit it from the arguments list and add `numberOfExecTime = kwargs['numberOfExecTime'] if 'numberOfExecTime' in kwargs else 1` as your first line.

Comment: I thinks that's almost what I did in the second variant using `pop` method with default value.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass multiple arguments: `args` should be a tuple containing the arguments to pass.

Now, you can pass `*args` instead of `args`.

(If you need to also pass kwargs to your method, then have in `get_execution_time` another argument `kwargs` and pass `**kwargs` to your `function`)

```
def get_execution_time(function, args=(), kwargs ={}, numberOfExecTime=1):
    return round(Timer(partial(function, *args, **kwargs)).timeit(numberOfExecTime), 5)
```

Comment: This is the best answer using existing code. However,@KL-7's have more expressive power if you want more control over the data you receive.

Comment: I hesitated to post the same proposal as proposed by KL-7 (in addition to the one I posted) but in my eyes the version I finally decided to post is the best version because the call of this function is more straightforward because there is no ambiguity of which of the passed arguments is passed to the function and which one is an argument of the method itself...

Comment: That's why I said it had *more expressive power*. I never said which answer was best because it is dependent on what the asker wants.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a timing decorator.

```
import time

def timeit(f):

    def timed(*args, **kw):

        ts = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        print 'func:%r args:[%r, %r] took: %2.4f sec' % \
          (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
        return result

    return timed
```

Using the decorator is easy either use annotations.

```
@timeit
def compute_magic(n):
     #function definition
     #....
```

Or re-alias the function you want to time.

```
compute_magic = timeit(compute_magic)
```

My blog post here has more information. http://blog.mattalcock.com/2013/2/24/timing-python-code/

Answer (score 0):

If `args` is a `list` of arguments you can expand it with `*args`:

```
return round(Timer(partial(function, args)).timeit(numberOfExecTime), 5)
```